# How to enumerate all modules of a 64-bit process?

Tags: c#

While writing a process debugger I came across a issue, the method used to enumerate all modules of a process only works for 32-bit processes. The method in question is [`EnumProcessModulesEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodulesex), part of Psapi. I tried using this function with the filter flag being ALL, DEFAULT & 64BIT, but I get the same result, 32-bit process' modules are enumerated and 64-bit process' modules are not. Anyone have a solution on how to enumerate all modules of a 64-bit process? And no, `Module32First`/`Module32Next` don't work reasons being:

1) In the name there is 32 which refers to 32-bit

2) `EnumProcessModulesEx` & `Module32*` stem from the same "`base function`"

Note: My application, the one which is using the enum function, is 64-bit.

Comment: "If the function is called by a 32-bit application running under WOW64, the dwFilterFlag option is ignored [...]" Is your application 32-bit by any chance (even if AnyCpu/Prefer 32-bit)?

Comment: Forgot to say, no my application is 64-bit

Comment: The link you provided is for 32 bit operating systems including the 32 bit version of Windows 7.  Try this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/process-and-thread-functions

Comment: @jdweng No, that api function exists in both 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows, and in WOW6432.